# Creating class in separate file (beginner)

Tags: c++, class, static-libraries

I am really new to C++, and I am trying to create a class in a separate file, and I ran into a problem. I basically copied the tutorial http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=16&number=15 from the newboston word for word. However, for the things don't work. I am getting this error when I am trying to run the main file:

```
C:\Users\Akavall\Desktop\C++ Stuff\New C++ stuff\class_try.o:class_try.cpp|| undefined reference to `Burrito::Burrito()'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Also, when I am creating the class. The **Workspace** icon is sitting by itself, while it is supposed to (I believe) include my .cpp and .h folders of the just created class.

My guess is that my paths are not set correctly somewhere, but I have no idea how to fix that. Any suggestions?

Here is the code that I am using:

Main file (class_try.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Burrito.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Burrito bo;
    return 0;
}
```

The class files:
Burrito.h

```
#ifndef BURRITO_H
#define BURRITO_H

class Burrito
{
    public:
        Burrito();

};

#endif // BURRITO_H
```

Burrito.cpp

```
#include "Burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Burrito::Burrito()
{
    cout<<"something silly"<<endl;
}
```

What should I do to fix the this problem?

Thank You in Advance

Edit:

I am using CodeBlocks, and I am on 32bit windows.

Comment: It looks like Burrito.o is not being linked. Maybe Burrito.cpp is not even being compiled, have you tried adding it to the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSVC like that tutorial you linked, you need to first create a project. After creating the project, add all the header (.h) and source (.cpp/.cxx) files that you want to include/compile in it. Now, MSVC makes this easy from this point; you can simply compile (as long as everything is properly added to your project) and it will compile things in order for you.

**Extra Information**
The information below is not directly pertinent to this issue (or at least doesn't seem that way since you're on Windows), but is intended to help your growth as a developer if you want it.

If, however, you ever decide to use a command line compiler (i.e. MingW) or work in a *nix environment, it is important to note that you need to explicitly compile each object (without linking; in gcc/mingw this flag is `-c`). Then at the end of compiling several unlinked object, you compile all the objects and the main source file together (with linking this time) and it will create one executable.

I would recommend, however, before trying a command line compiler that you get comfortable/familiar with doing this process through an IDE. Since it is generally an automated process anyway (i.e. most developers end up writing Makefile's for this kind of thing, realistically) you do not really lose too much (immediately, anyway) by not doing this. It is just something to be aware of as you learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it, everything works now, and thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Using command line compiler you can try this:

```
g++ class_try.cpp Burrito.cpp -o executable_name
```

This will link your two .cpp files and create an executable file and you can run that executable file just by typing

```
./executable_name
```

Comment: I believe your are missing an `-o`. I would do `g++ class_try.cpp Burrito.cpp -o executable_name` or `g++ -std=c++11 class_try.cpp Burrito.cpp -o executable_name`